# Way to simulate or calculate event numbers in survival analysis?

Tags: survival, meta-analysis, proportional-hazards

I would like to conduct a meta analysis on a subgroup that's often included in larger studies but not typically studied alone. I am trying to investigate the effect the presence or absence of a covariate has on event rate. One of the studies that meets our inclusion criteria has 4 categories of this covariate, no presence, and 3 increasing levels of presence and presents the hazard ratios for each of those categories. Given the size of all 4 categories of the covariate and total number of events in the subgroup, is it possible to find the number of events in each specific category using this information and the HRs? It was suggested this could be explored through simulation but I'm not sure where to start with that.